# Cannot debug or hit breakpoints inside express middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I thought I had this working before but, even after invalidating webstorm's caches this still doesn't work. Like the title says, I'm unable to hit any breakpoints with inthe statement below. I read somewhere that the statement "*is an assignment expression and the function is not called at the frame, so there is nothing to step int*o". Is there a way to rewrite this so that I can debug?

```
const request = require('request');
const Feed = require('../models/feed');
const async = require('async');
const FeedParser = require('feedparser');
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator/check');
const {sanitizeParam} = require('express-validator/filter');
const feedParserOptions = {addmeta: 'false'};
const authorEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/authors/';
const debug = require('debug');


exports.createAuthor = [

check('firstName', 'First name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
check('lastName', 'Last name must be specified').isLength({min: 1}).trim(),
sanitizeParam('firstName').trim().escape(),
sanitizeParam('lastName').trim().escape(),


(req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    const author = new Author({
        firstName: req.query.firstName,
        lastName: req.query.lastName,
    });

    debug(req.query.firstName);
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        let query = {
            $or: [{firstName: {$regex: req.query.firstName, $options: 'i'}},
                {lastName: {$regex: req.query.lastName, $options: 'i'}}],
        }; // TODO this regex fails if a parameter is missing.


        Author.findOne(query).sort([['lastName', 'ascending']]).exec((err, existingAuthor) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            if (!(existingAuthor == null)) {
                let result = {status: 'Author already exists: ', author_id: String(existingAuthor.id)};
                res.locals.messages = result;
                next();
            } else if (existingAuthor == null) {
                author.save(function(err, newAuthor) {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    }

                    let result = {status: 'New author saved', author_id: String(newAuthor.id)};
                    res.locals.messages = result;
                    next();
                });
            }
        });
    }
},
];
```

Comment: Which part are you trying to step through?

Comment: I'm trying to find the value of req. So, I would set my breakpoint somewhere in the first 10 lines of the function.